# Running Jenkins behind Apache ends up in a redirect loop

Tags: apache, jenkins, kerberos

I am trying to setup Jenkins behind Apache and facing issues with user authentication. This is my vhost config file -

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

LoadModule auth_kerb_module modules/mod_auth_kerb.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jenkins-staging.lb.company.com
    ServerAlias jenkins-staging

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8019/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8019/
<LocationMatch "/.+">
    Use Kerberos /path/to/keytab/file
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when I try to access Jenkins from browser using http://jenkins-staging.lb.company.com/jenkins it is being redirected to http://jenkins-staging.lb.company.com/jenkins/secured and here it shows the error - **"This webpage has a redirect loop"**

The network analysis shows authorization headers being properly sent/received. Could anyone guide me as to what the issue here might be and how to solve it ?

Comment: Did you ever solved this?